# Q: Custom field for Events lookup

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, civicrm-home

I need to add a custom field, for contacts, to search all events. As part of the organisation, there are meetings created for department heads to discuss appointments to our programme areas. I am creating an "appointment" custom fields set. I want to have a field that allows the user to search for that event and added it the contact record.

Thanks in advance.
A.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether Appointment custom fields should be on the event or participant record.  Please edit your question to give examples of some of the custom fields you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show that these are appointment discussions then you could create an [Event Type](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/what-is-civievent/#event-types) of 'Appointment Discussion' then people can search by type.

If you want to record more info (eg level of appointment, department etc) you can create custom fields on Events.  See [the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/) for details of how to add them.

You might want to do both - ie create an Event Type and then create the appointment custom fields only on that Event Type so that they don't show on all your other events.

Comment: Hi there, to clarify, on the contact record (e.g. one of our researchers), I've created a custom field set (with a bunch of fields that the members appointment team requested. These roughly match what we had on the old Access system, so we can migrate/import most of them). One of them stored (on the old system) the meeting ID, that the decision was taken to appoint someone as a researcher). We currently are using CiviEvents for all our events, so I was hoping to have a custom field that works as a lookup to the events currently in Civi, to fullfil the same function as the old system...

Comment: Ah ok - you could store the event id in your custom field but I don't know of an easy way to turn that into a selector of events.  I think you want something like a Contact Reference field but for Events.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.